# Coupon Collector's Problem with Subset

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

I have a variation of the Coupon Collector's Problem which can be state as follows.

"Given a set $N$ of $n$ different kinds of coupons and a subset $K\subset N$ of $k$ kinds of coupons, with $k<n$, what is the expected number of draws you need to obtain at least one copy of each coupon of the set $K$. Each draw takes a single coupon from $N$ with same probability for each kind."

My previous approach was to enumerate the elements of $K$, lets say $l_1,l_2,...,l_k$ and associate each element $l_i$ with an integer $t_i$ which is the number of the trial in which we get $l_i$.

I'm "defining" a success to be "get a element of $K$ which we didn't get yet".

Then I tried to compute the probability of getting all the coupons from $K$ in $T$ trials base on the multiplicative rule. For simplicity, I considered $t_i<t_j$ if $i<j$ by now: we need $t_1-1$ fails, which have probability $1-\frac{k}{n}$ each and then a success with probability $\frac{k}{n}$. After that, the probability of a success decrease to $\frac{k-1}{n}$ since we already an element of $K$ and we are going to have more $t_2 - t_1 - 1$ fails with probability $1-\frac{k-1}{n}$.

With this line of thinking I got the probability of getting $l_i$ in trial $t_i$ is $\prod_{i=1}^k (\frac{k-i+1}{n})(1-\frac{k-i+1}{n})^{t_i - t_{i-1}-1}$ given that $i<j$ imples $t_i < t_j$ and may define $t_0 = 0$ and $t_k = T$ to keep it consistent.

So to consider all the possible orders for getting $l_1,...,l_k$ we can multiply by the number of ways to order this list, it is $k!$. My next idea was to take in count the fact that if we fix $t_i$, for all $i \neq j $, and let $t_j$ vary, we will have exclusives situations and we could compute the probability of getting all the coupons in $K$ in $T$ trials by making summations over $t_1,t_2,...,t_k$. But things get really complicated very soon.

I don't even know if that is a reasonable approach to the problem or if there is one easier.

Any help would be appreciable.

Thank You

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  As you suggest, the methods used to solve the standard Coupon Collector's Problem are also applicable here.

Comment: Merely stating a problem without context is not a good practice here.  You can place the problem in a clearer context for Readers by adding what approach you tried and the difficulty it led to, where you encountered the problem and why it is interesting or important to you, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is substantially different from the original coupon collector problem.

The expected number of draws to collect the first coupon is $1/(k/n) = n/k$.  The expected number of additional draws to collect the next coupon is $1/((k-1)/n)=n/(k-1)$. etc.

Therefore they find the $k$ coupons in, on average, $nH_k$ draws.